# MS Access VBA - Decimal Subtraction and Multiplication gives unexpected result

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here's a test code which demonstrates the issue : The result is 6.9999999 instead of 7.

```
Sub test_calc()
old_ic = 0.7
new_ic = 0.63
adj = (old_ic - new_ic) * 100
End Sub
```

Is the result 6.9999999 expected behavior?

I was expecting 7 for the result.

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/669576)